# AngularJS $http withCredentials - clear on logout

Tags: angularjs, passport.js

I am using PassportJS on server side for authentication and on client side I use `$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;` to ensure cookies are properly received, set and transmitted on further requests.

When I logout, I want to clear all browser cookies that were set because of using `$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It should be resolved on the server side, usually, you set MaxAge=-1 for cookies, then the browser will remove them automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use req.session.destroy in logout route to destroy the session. Like

```
app.get('/logout', function(req,res){
 req.logOut();
 req.session.destroy(function (err) {
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

Or use

```
module.exports.getLogout = function (req, res, next) {
req.logout();
req.session.destroy(function (err) {
    if (!err) {
        res.status(200).clearCookie('connect.sid', {path: '/'}).json({status: "Success"});
    } else {
        // handle error...
    }
    });
};
```